# Messed object when import to unity (duplicate

Tags: objects, export, import, unity

i have model in blender
[image: my model in blender]

Then i export to .obj and import it to unity. When i drag this file, i got this
[image: my model in unity]

i have also tried export to fbx, dae, 3ds
But when i import 3ds, i got this icon

[image: icon import 3ds in unity]

Can aonyone tell me my mistakes?

Sorry if my english so bad :(

Comment: In Object mode select the object, press Ctrl+A > Scale to apply it, then (if grey normals still present) enter Edit mode and recalculate normals with Ctrl+N with all selected

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19325/why-is-my-mesh-inversed-when-imported-to-unity and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15802/mesh-imported-to-unity-is-inside-out

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

Looks like i have duplicate hidden mesh on outliner